# I need solution and explanation about a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table and i want to create new table from this table such that each student who got highest marks from all the three subject will be inserted along with student_id and marks.

I am using mysql 5.5

[image: Table.png]

Answer should be like this.

[Table2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8fhN.png)

Comment: No images, please. Use formatted text instead!

Comment: use `MAX` and `GROUP BY`, or something

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this table

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`student_id` int, `subject` varchar(10), `marks` int)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (`student_id`, `subject`, `marks`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Hindi', 70),
    (1, 'English', 80),
    (1, 'Maths', 90),
    (2, 'Hindi', 40),
    (2, 'English', 50),
    (2, 'Maths', 60),
    (3, 'Hindi', 40),
    (3, 'English', 60),
    (3, 'Maths', 70)
;
```

and this select statemnet

```
Select 
  t.student_id,
  t.Subject,
  t.marks
From
  table1 t inner Join 
    (SELECT student_id,MAX(marks) mmarks FROM table1 Group by student_id) m1
  on t.marks = m1.mmarks and t.student_id = m1.student_id;
```

You get following result:

```
student_id  Subject     marks
1           Maths       90
2           Maths       60
3           Maths       70
```

With the mysql 5.5 you have to self join the table

Comment: Thanks i got my answer.